# Use a twig filter in template_from_string function

Tags: twig, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, twig-extension, twig-filter

I am creating a multilingual website with October CMS, using *Rainlab Translate* and *Vojta Svoboda Twig Extensions* plugins.
I'm using the twig function `template_from_string` to create a link button in one of my template files.

Everything works as expected *if* I use a `|media` filter in the link attribute, to get the url of a media file.
But, if I use a `|page` filter, to get a page url, I get an error for **Unknown "page" filter**.

```
<!-- It works: -->
<div>
    {% set btn = {
        'link': 'foobar.jpg',
        'label': 'Where is FooBar »'
    } %}
    {{ include(template_from_string('<a class="btn btn-promo btn-white move" href="{{ btn.link|media }}" role="button">{{ btn.label }}</a>')) }}
</div>


<!-- It does not work: -->
<div>
    {% set btn = {
        'link': 'foobar',
        'label': 'Where is FooBar »'
    } %}
    {{ include(template_from_string('<a class="btn btn-promo btn-white move" href="{{ btn.link|page }}" role="button">{{ btn.label }}</a>')) }}
</div>
```

I'm stuck on this problem and my question is: How can I get both filters work?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Any reason at all to use `template_from_string` for this?

Comment: We created a template structure where template_from_string is useful, thus avoiding to hardcode twig variables (we can use "variable of variable")

Comment: Strange, nothing that could not be solved with a simple `{% include 'template.html' with { 'link': 'foobar', 'label': 'Fobar?', } %}` or in the "worst" case a macro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overlooking stuff :)

You can use like this

```
<div>
    {% set btn = {
        'link': 'fooba'|page, <-- HERE
        'label': 'Where is FooBar »'
    } %}
    {{ include(template_from_string('<a class="btn btn-promo btn-white move" href="{{ btn.link }}" role="button">{{ btn.label }}</a>')) }}
</div>
```

you can use `filter on main scope` and just pass `filtered value` directly. you do not need to use filters inside `template_from_string`

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: as you can imagine i'm a newbie...  i spent the all morning trying to find your simple solution. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: ha ha, happens but now you know solution :)